# keep columns within rows that are equal to or greater than a given value

Tags: r, sorting, unique, rows

Not sure how to word this as all the R coding I know would remove entire rows based on the sum values but here is an example of what I want to do.

I want to take taxonomic information taken from individual sites but only keep the levels which are represented a minimum of three times in the overall sample.

For example in the table below although at River mile 15 the order Diptera was identified as being present once - Diptera overall appear 38 times across the sample so I want to keep that row. Same for the genus Chaetocladius which although it appears once in RM0.7 is present 5 times in the sample, so I would keep it.

Also, for cases where the one level appears enough times to keep there are those to the right that are rare and need to be removed and replaced with NA instead. For example, as in the case at RM15 with the Order Blattoidea or RM80 where the species Chironomus atroviridis are present only once but Insecta and Chironomus are present enough times to keep, thus I want to keep those levels but replace the rest with NAs.

```
RM  phylum      class   order   family          genus           species             Sum
0.5 Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chaetocladius   Chaetocladius mel   1
15  Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera NA              NA              NA  1
15  Arthropoda  Insecta Blattoidea   NA         NA              NA  1
0.7 Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chaetocladius   NA  1
54  Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chaetocladius   NA  2
35  Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chaetocladius   NA  2
80  Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chironomus  Chironomus atroviridis  2
80  Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chironomus  Chironomus bifurcatus   1
0.5 Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chironomus  Chironomus bifurcatus   29
```

The new output would look like this -

```
RM  phylum  class   order   family  genus   species Sum
0.5 Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chaetocladius   NA  1
15  Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera NA              NA              NA  1
15  Arthropoda  Insecta NA      NA              NA              NA  1
0.7 Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chaetocladius   NA  1
54  Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chaetocladius   NA  2
35  Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chaetocladius   NA  2
80  Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chironomus      NA  2
80  Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chironomus  Chironomus bifurcatus   1
0.5 Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chironomus  Chironomus bifurcatus   29
```

I have aggregated lists for each level of those taxa with values of 3 or greater and I thought maybe I could work my way thru each (from Phylum to species) but can't figure out how to do it.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a simpler way to do this but this provides the output you want.  It is wrapped in a function `clean_data` where you can specify how many times something must be present to keep.  In this case, those not present more than twice in the provided data are replaced with NA.  Does this fit your needs?

```
dat <- read.table(header=T, text='
RM  phylum      class   order   family          genus           species             Sum
0.5 Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chaetocladius   "Chaetocladius mel"   1
                  15  Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera NA              NA              NA  1
                  15  Arthropoda  Insecta Blattoidea   NA         NA              NA  1
                  0.7 Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chaetocladius   NA  1
                  54  Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chaetocladius   NA  2
                  35  Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chaetocladius   NA  2
                  80  Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chironomus  "Chironomus atroviridis"  2
                  80  Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chironomus  "Chironomus bifurcatus"   1
                  0.5 Arthropoda  Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chironomus  "Chironomus bifurcatus"   29
                  ')

clean_data <- function(dat, repeats){
  # get the counts of each level within each column
  counts <- sapply(dat[,colnames(dat) != c("RM", "Sum")], table)

  # convert data to matrix for indexing
  dat <- as.matrix(dat)

  indices <- unlist(
    # get indices of where the elements are in data matrix
    lapply(
      # remove list elements that are character(0)
      Filter(length,
                  # find which levels are only present 'repeats' times
                  lapply(counts,FUN = function(x) names(which(x < repeats)))),
      FUN = function(y) which(dat %in% y)))

  # set indices to NA
  dat[indices] <- NA
  return(as.data.frame(dat))
}

clean_data(dat, 2)

> clean_data(dat, 2)
    RM     phylum   class   order       family         genus               species Sum
1  0.5 Arthropoda Insecta Diptera Chironomidae Chaetocladius                  <NA>   1
2 15.0 Arthropoda Insecta Diptera         <NA>          <NA>                  <NA>   1
3 15.0 Arthropoda Insecta    <NA>         <NA>          <NA>                  <NA>   1
4  0.7 Arthropoda Insecta Diptera Chironomidae Chaetocladius                  <NA>   1
5 54.0 Arthropoda Insecta Diptera Chironomidae Chaetocladius                  <NA>   2
6 35.0 Arthropoda Insecta Diptera Chironomidae Chaetocladius                  <NA>   2
7 80.0 Arthropoda Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chironomus                  <NA>   2
8 80.0 Arthropoda Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chironomus Chironomus bifurcatus   1
9  0.5 Arthropoda Insecta Diptera Chironomidae    Chironomus Chironomus bifurcatus  29
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This works and I agree there must be an easier way but I haven't found it.